# Email Service is communicate Magento to angular front-end

Tags: magento-2.1, email, angularjs

I will make website front-end in angular,but back-end is magento.Please Tell me how to communicate reset password,forgot password and other email-service.

Comment: If you're going down the 'headless' Magento route (i.e. Using the backend but building your own frontend) then you'll want to investigate the Magento API, since that is how your frontend will communicate with the backend. Start here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Comment: Please give any other solution

Comment: Save yourself the hassle. Get someone who knows what they are doing to build it.